# Binary classification using RNN not going beyond 50% accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, rnn, binary-classification

I am trying to find out the reason behind why my RNN network won't go beyond 50% for binary classification. My input data is of the shape:

```
X.shape
- TensorShape([9585, 25, 2])
```

My labels are a single dimension vector with the values `1.0` and `0.0`:

```
y
- <tf.Tensor: shape=(9585,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 1.], dtype=float32)>
```

I have created the classification class as below:

```
batch_size = 4 # hyperparameter
max_seqlen = 25 # the second dimension (time) in the data, first being the number of datapoints
features = 2 # 2 features per timestamp

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, max_seqlen, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bilstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(max_seqlen, features))
        )
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu") # nn with relu non-linearity
        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid") # for final binary prediction
    def call(self, x):
        x = self.bilstm(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        return x
model = Model(max_seqlen)
model.build(input_shape=(batch_size, max_seqlen, features))
model.summary()
```

I am preparing the dataset and running the training and validation as follows:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000)
n = len(y)
test_size = n // 8
val_size = (n - test_size) // 10


test_dataset = dataset.take(test_size)
val_dataset = dataset.skip(test_size).take(val_size)
train_dataset = dataset.skip(test_size + val_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(batch_size)


model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer="adam",
    metrics=["accuracy"]
)

# train
data_dir = "./data"
logs_dir = os.path.join("./logs")
best_model_file = os.path.join(data_dir, "best_model.h5")

checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(best_model_file,
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_best_only=True)
tensorboard = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logs_dir)
num_epochs = 10
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=num_epochs,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, tensorboard])
```

During the epochs, the accuracy does not improve beyond 50%. Is there something wrong with what I am doing? I also tried normalizing my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

To split your dataset try this :

```
train_ds = dataset.take(train_size)    
val_ds = dataset.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test_ds = dataset.skip(train_size).skip(val_size)
```

Comment: Don't see the point. I am making test dataset, skipping and taking validation dataset and then skipping both test and validation datasets.

Comment: Using your way of splitting datasets, found some samples appearing in both test and val, or other way around. Anyway it is great if you found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The `y` were not correct to the corresponding `X`.